# Debian 9/Ubuntu: Which repository sources can I add to sources.list in order to get more up-to-date packages?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository, apt

(I've already run `apt-get update`.)

I installed `php` from the default Debian repositories, but found that it's only version 7.0. This is now 4 years old, from 2015...

Last year, I had been developing a project using the most recent stable PHP version at the time (7.2), which I had installed with Homebrew. Now I'm trying to set up a Debian machine, but I cannot compile my projects because Debian's default packages are so old. I expect that I'll have issues with other obsolete packages as well, which is why I'm generalizing my question beyond PHP.

Is there a repository (or repositories) that I can add to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file that will grant me access to more recent packages? Homebrew is able to find them, so it must be possible.

Comment: What about updating your distribution?

Comment: Debian 10 has not been released yet.

Comment: If you want to be more updated, you should use `testing` instead of `stable`. Mixing sources is a source of problem. Avoid if you can (else: document everything. Learn how to unistall/downgrade packages, and get a backup also of system files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/) you can find online repo list generator with a good explanation on each repo. read it for more info. by the way you need do what @JosephWorks said to get most recent packages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the local package lists:

   sudo apt-get update
2. Next, run updates on the software packages to prepare for the operating system upgrade:

   sudo apt-get upgrade
3. Finally, run the distribution upgrade:

   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade